# Video not uploading on Vimeo using PHP API, gives exception unable to upgrade

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

The Vimeo API was working perfectly then without any reason gave this exception:

> Unable to get an upload ticket.[Unable to upgrade video to 1080p HD. Please get in touch with the app's creator]

The upgrade setting in the API is set to false but still this exception is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the API, and should now be resolved!